# script for auto adding routing table entries

Tags: bash, vpn, script, shell-script, osx-mountain-lion

There are a lot of remote agents that use Mountain Lion. We want only the directories on our intranet to be go through the VPN tunnel and all other traffic to go direct out. So to do this I had to add the `ip-up` file to /etc/ppp.

I want to create a script that will create the `ip-up` file with our IP subnets for themin the `/etc/ppp` directory.

I have made an attempt or two at this and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Nick, could you tell me what I'm not understanding in your question.  OS X has a built in VPN client (Cisco, L2TP, PPTP).  You are going to have people use this to connect to your VPN server while they are at home.  You are trying to set it up so that peoples use of a resource is forced through the VPN.  What kind of VPN have you set up (what is your VPN server)?  How are you doing domain control?

Comment: It is an L2TP but I am not sure what you mean by domain control. We have active directory that we allow VPN access through.

Comment: Active Directory is a way to do Domain control (Open directory is another one).

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on a mac in the built in VPN that makes all traffic go over the VPN:
[image]

Comment: As I said above, we do NOT want to send all traffic through VPN. It is slower to route it that way for us. I have this working correctly. I want to make a script to do this faster. I can lay out all the steps it takes.

Comment: I do this to my house, with a Mac.  My configuration is this: I have a Mac Mini Server that has DNS running on it.  It's running Open Directory.  I have a VPN server running through it and my AirPort.  When I connect to my VPN, anything that is served to my account (SMB, AFP, Printer, Fax) is available.

Comment: Uncheck the box above. that says "Send all traffic over VPN connection."  This will cause only the resources available through your domain control to travel the VPN.